# Changing a SCSS $var, with &.conditionalClass

Tags: css, sass

I am looking for a way to change a few attributes in my components SCSS.
I thought by adding a `$var: false !default;`, and then adding a conditional class

```
&.conditionalClass { // If the class exists on the element
  $var: true; // Change the variable to true.
}
```

And then using `@if/@else` statements, I could change the values of those attributes to what I wanted to happen.

```
@if ($var == true) {
  backgroud-color: red;
} @else {
  background-color: green;
}
```

But that does not appear to work... as the variable `$var` isn't being updated per instance of the component, and so the value always evaluates to `$var: true;`, despite the fact that some of the component instances don't have the `conditionalClass`.

So I guess I'm asking why this works on a per-component basis:

```
background-color: red;
&.conditionalClass {
  background-color: green;
}
```

And how I could go about replicating that into this type of syntax:

```
$var: false !default;

&.conditionalClass {
  $var: true;
}

@if $var == true {
  background-color: green;
} @else {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Now, I understand that the

```
&.conditionalClass {
  $var: true;
}
```

Is locally scoped, so it doesn't get pushed down to the descendants of the parent class, but Is there a way to make it push the `$var` value to the top level parent class, and have it cascade down?

Comment: So you are looking for a feature like, if and element (say p) has a class(say conditionalClass), the value of the global variable should change.
This is not possible.

Comment: @SudiptoRoy you nailed it. I unfortunately came to the same conclusion, and ended up having to use a mixin that was evaluated by the conditionalClass. So it is originally called in the parent with the mixin Var set to false, and then it's called if the conditionalClass is present, with the mixin var as true, and then the logic is handled in the mixin.